# XML Deserialization with Parent Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Items>
  <Category Name="Alfa">
    <Item Name="A1" Signature="3136323700000000"/>
    <Item Name="A2" Signature="3136333400000000"/>
    <Item Name="A3" Signature="3136323800000000"/>
    <Item Name="A4" Signature="3136333300000000"/>
    ... More Items
  </Category>
  <Category Name="Beta">
    <Item Name="B1" Signature="3136323700000000"/>
    <Item Name="B2" Signature="3136333400000000"/>
    <Item Name="B3" Signature="3136323800000000"/>
    <Item Name="B4" Signature="3136333300000000"/>
    ... More Items
  </Category>
  ... More Categories
</Items>
```

The class I would like to use to deserialize it looks like this:

```
public sealed class Item
{
    private String m_Category;
    private String m_Name;
    private String m_Signature;

    public String Category
    {
        get { return m_Category; }
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get { return m_Name; }
    }

    public String Signature
    {
        get { return m_Signature; }
    }

    public Item(String category, String name, String signature)
    {
        m_Category = category;
        m_Name = name;
        m_Signature = signature;
    }
}
```

How can I deserialize it so that the Category property is taken from the parent element's Name attribute? If it's not possible, which alternative method could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Linq To Xml?

```
var items = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                .Descendants("Item")
                .Select(c => new Item(c.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value, 
                                      c.Attribute("Name").Value, 
                                      c.Attribute("Signature").Value))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Where has `GameItem` come from...?

Comment: @Duane It was in OP's question. I see that he updated it and so did I.  Is this all for downvoting?

Comment: I paster the wrong piece of code at the beginning of my class. There's no need to downvote for a different reference name.